# Django - How can I return error messages if user already exists during registration?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-forms

Using Django REST, and I'm trying to implement simple warnings that warn users if an `email` and/or `username` is currently in use, during registration flow.

I've tried implementing it using `UniqueValidator`, but there does not to be much information about it. Also wondering if I should just ditch that and use something else.

Here is my serializer:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.validators import UniqueValidator
from users.models import User


class CustomUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(
        required=True, 
        validators=[UniqueValidator( queryset=User.objects.all(), message="This email is already in use")])

    username = serializers.CharField(
        required=True, 
        validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all(), message="This username is already in use")])

    password = serializers.CharField(min_length=8, write_only=True)
    first_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=30)
    subscribed = serializers.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'username', 'password','first_name','last_name','subscribed')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        password = validated_data.pop('password', None)
        instance = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
        if password is not None:
            instance.set_password(password)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

view.py:

```
class CustomUserCreate(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def post(self, request, format='json'):
        serializer = CustomUserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = serializer.save()
            if user:
                json = serializer.data
                return Response(json, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Please let me know how I can make this validation process as effective as possible.

Answer (score 0):

On your views.py

```
def post(self, request, format='json'):
   try:
       User.objects.get(username = username)  #Check first if the user is present
       #If present return a JSON response 
   except:
       user = User(email="test",username="test@gmail.com",...)
       user.save()
       #return a json  response
```

Comment: Is there any way where I could use the messages I already created in my serializer?

Answer (score 0):

Please check this

```
django.http import HttpResponse
def post(self, request, format='json'):
       if User.objects.get(username = username).exists()  
           #Check first if the user is present
           return HttpResponse("Username used already")
       if User.objects.get(email= email).exists()  
           #Check first if the email is present
           return HttpResponse("Email used already")
       user = User(email="test",username="test@gmail.com",...)
       user.save()
       #return a JSON response
```